# Where should I upload my code for others to get involved in?

Tags: php, web

I have made my own php MVC framework and have also written its documentation. It is about 80% complete. Now basically I am looking for a way so that other developers should be able to analyze my code and possibly join hands for its further development and improvement and also they should be able to browse through the documentation (html files).

I know about google app engine, but it is currently and mainly for python. So where should i upload my php code which should be runnable and the documentation (html files) browseable?

Comment: You can share your code with me :) I too have created my own mvc framework and would like to look at others mvc frameworks :]

Comment: @AntonioCS: Thanks i would definitely share it with you once i upload it, thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**Github**](http://github.com/) comes to mind. It's free for Open Source projects, and supports a lot of "social coding" functions.

If you prefer Subversion Version Control, take a look at [**Google Code**](http://code.google.com/).

**HTML Hosting**

Github can even [**host static HTML pages**](http://github.com/blog/272-github-pages):

> GitHub Pages allow you to publish web content to a github.com subdomain named after your username. With Pages, publishing web content becomes as easy as pushing to your GitHub repository.

**Running PHP**

Running PHP files is not possible neither on Github, nor Google Code. I don't know any free, ad-free PHP hosting offers that are worth their salt - probably because of the huge danger of misuse. If it's an option at all, I think the best thing to do is chip in a few dollars/euros and get a small commercial hosting package somewhere.

Comment: +1 for GitHub. Google Code works, but from what I've seen github can do wonders for exposure of a new codebase.

Comment: @Pekka: ok what about html files, will they be browseable?

Comment: also i visited that site, and i saw this link on top : Pricing and Signup

Comment: @Sarfraz Github has a built-in Wiki but AFAIK they don't host "raw" HTML files for browsing.

Comment: @Sarfraz they're free for OS projects.

Comment: @Pekka: This means the two things i am looking for are not possible on this site, right?

Comment: @Sarfraz "Now basically I am looking for a way so that other developers should be able to analyze my code and possibly join hands for its further development and improvement" this and more is all possible with github, and very difficult to set up on a hosting package.

Comment: @Sarfraz no problem, I want to try Github myself soon, and the HTML hosting is *very* good to know about :)

Comment: @Pekka: that's true, currently i am browsing through that to know more about it :)

Answer (score 1):

[GitHub,](http://github.com) [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.com) and [Google Code](http://code.google.com) are all great places to make your project public and get others involved.

But these sites will only host your code, documentation, maybe provide you a forum, a mailing list and a bug tracker. They usually does not offer you a hosting for an instance of your app. (It would be costly and difficult to do that: all project have very specific runtime requirements and most of them are not even in PHP or not webapps at all.) But you could easily google for "free php web hosting", upload your site there, and then link from the project site.

(Btw. google app engine is also for Java!)

Comment: sourceforge actually allows you to host your own app: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Developer%20web .

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{   int selection;
printf("this is a program to build a calculator program \n");
printf("for addition press 1 \n");
printf("for multiplication press 2 \n");
printf("for subtraction enter 3 \n");
printf("for division enter 4 \n");    /* this is cool */
scanf("%d",&selection);
switch(selection)
{
    case 1: printf("ADDITION \n");    /* this is for addition */
            int a,b,c;
            printf("enter a value into a \n");
            scanf("%d",&a);
            printf("enter a value into b \n");
            scanf("%d",&b);
            c=a+b; /*logic of the addition phase */
            printf("the answer is %d \n",c);
            break;
    case 2: printf("MULTIPLICATION \n");  /* this is for multiplication */
            int e,f,g; /* here we took variables to store values in it */
            printf("enter a value for a \n");
            scanf("%d",&e);
            printf("enter a value for b \n");
            scanf("%d",&f);
            g=e*f;  /* logic of the multiplication phase */
            printf("the answer is %d  \n",g);
            break;
    case 3: printf("SUBTRACTION \n");
            int h,i,j;
            printf("enter a value for a /n");
            scanf("%d",&h);
            printf("enter a value for b \n");
            scanf("%d",&i);
            j=h-i; /* this is the logic for subtraction */
            printf("the answer is %d ",j);
            break ;
    case 4: printf("DIVISION \n");
            float k,l,m;
            printf("enter a value into a \n");
            scanf("%f",&i);
            printf("enter a value into b \n");
            scanf("%f",&m);
            k=i/m; /*this is the logic used for division */
            printf("the answer is %.2f \n",k);
            break;

   default: printf("error \n");
            break;  /* this is used to break the execution of the program */

   }

  getchar();
   return 0;   /* this return a value */
 }
```

Comment: Any explanation to this?